# Validate assosiations rails mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongomapper

How to validate assosiations

I have advertiser belongs_to city
and i need check uniqueness name to city

Chunk of my model

```
  key :name, String , :required => true ,:unique => true ,:scope => :city_id
  key :city_id, ObjectId   , :required => true


  belongs_to :city
```

I tried

```
  key :name, String , :required => true ,:unique => true ,:scope => :city_id
```

where i'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of what you have, you can just put:

```
key :name, String, :required => true
```

And on a separate line:

```
validates :name,  :uniqueness => {:scope => :city_id}
```

Comment: +1 also instead of required attribute you can use rails [`presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) helper :)